# Array.reduce() group by object field and extend all other fields to their corresponding grouped object field

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, group-by, document

I want to create a group-By function for an object, where I group an array by a field and then I kind of "coerce" all fields of the upcoming documents from the array  by their corresponding group-object fields.

```
const groupInDoc = (array, fieldname) => {
    let groupedResultDoc = array.reduce((carDocs, current) => {  
        let keyCount = Object.keys(current).length;
        let obj = {};
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(current)) { 
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);           

            //check if key is same as the fieldname to group-by.
            if (key == fieldname) {
            } else {
                obj[key] = value;
            }

        }      
        if (carDocs.hasOwnProperty(current[fieldname])) {
            //if (Array.isArray(carDocs[current[fieldname]])){
            carDocs[current[fieldname]] = obj;
            //}                                
        } else {            
            carDocs[current[fieldname]] =  obj;

        }  
        return carDocs;     
    }, Object.create({}));

    return groupedResultDoc;
}
```

I now have the problem how can I extend the fields of the grouped objects by their other corresponding object fields from the array objects?

E.g If my grouped object has a subdocument for a group-key with a field array and a field "string", then I want to push all new array values from matching group objects into the old array, and also I want to coerce the strings together with "+"... how can I do that?

**EDIT**: My original data:

```
let doc = [
    {
        "car": "Ford",
        "prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],
        "model": "SUV"
    },
    {
        "car": "Ford",
        "prices": ["99","88","77"],
        "model": "T3"
    },
    {
        "car": "Toyota",
        "prices": ["33","44","55"],
        "model": "Subaru"
    },
    {
        "car": "Toyota",
        "prices": ["66", "50", "22"],
        "model": "Cheyenne"
    },
    {
        "car": "Peugeot",
        "prices": ["1","2","3"],
        "model" : "503"
    }
];
```

My result is:

```
CarDocs:  { Ford: { prices: [ '99', '88', '77' ], model: 'T3' },
  Toyota: { prices: [ '66', '50', '22' ], model: 'Cheyenne' },
  Peugeot: { prices: [ '1', '2', '3' ], model: '503' } }
```

but it should be:

```
CarDocs:  { Ford: { prices: ["12", "3", "5", "1", '99', '88', '77' ], model: 'T3', 'SUV' },
  Toyota: { prices: [33","44","55", '66', '50', '22' ], model: 'Cheyenne', 'Subaru' },
  Peugeot: { prices: [ '1', '2', '3' ], model: '503' } }
```

Comment: Can you post your original data? I meant that initial array

Comment: yes sorry, I added it in my original post

Comment: `model` will have to be an array here, or a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge each object depending on key name on each loop with reduce:

```js
let doc = [{"car": "Ford","prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],"model": "SUV"},{"car": "Ford","prices": ["99","88","77"],"model": "T3"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["33","44","55"],"model": "Subaru"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["66", "50", "22"],"model": "Cheyenne"},{"car": "Peugeot","prices": ["1","2","3"],"model" : "503"}];

let CarDoc = doc.reduce((a, {car, prices, model}) => {
  if(a[car]) {
    prices.forEach(p => a[car].prices.push(p))
    a[car].model = [...a[car].model, model]
  } else {
    a[car] = {prices, model:[model]}
  }
  return a
}, {})

console.log(CarDoc)
```

Less readable, single line version:

```js
let doc = [{"car": "Ford","prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],"model": "SUV"},{"car": "Ford","prices": ["99","88","77"],"model": "T3"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["33","44","55"],"model": "Subaru"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["66", "50", "22"],"model": "Cheyenne"},{"car": "Peugeot","prices": ["1","2","3"],"model" : "503"}];

let CarDoc = doc.reduce((a, {car, prices, model}) => a[car] ? {...a, [car]: {prices: a[car].prices.concat(prices), model: a[car].model.concat(model)}} : {...a, [car]: {prices, model:[model]}}, {})

console.log(CarDoc)
```

EDIT:

```js
let doc = [{"car": "Ford", test: 'test', "prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],"model": "SUV"},{"car": "Ford", test: 'test', "prices": ["99","88","77"],"model": "T3"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["33","44","55"],"model": "Subaru"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["66", "50", "22"],"model": "Cheyenne"},{"car": "Peugeot","prices": ["1","2","3"],"model" : "503"}];

let CarDoc = doc.reduce((a, {car, ...rest}) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    if(a[car]) {
      a[car][k] = [...a[car][k] || [], v]
    } else {
      a[car] = {...a[car], [k]: [v]}
    }
  })
  
  return a
}, {})

console.log(CarDoc)
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to generalize the code, so that it works for all fields and field types? would I have to check what typeof field the field is?

Comment: You could, but yes, you would have to accommodate for the type. I think when you merge the prices, it would be better to have it in a format like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` when merging, so you can access related values by index. So, you could put everything in an array, and push the values to the corresponding array each time.

Comment: nice,. I am impressed how "easy" this is (in lines of code) I was  trying for some hours to get it right, I got it but far more complicated that this, can you explain me where you learned this? And what does  `a[car][k] = [...a[car][k] || [], v]` do? I know it creates the key `a[car][k]` on the fly if it does not exist, but  `[...a[car][k] || [], v]` creates an array with the value a[car][k] with an empty array as fallback, or the value itself ? what does it mean?

Comment: You're right, `...` will spread out all the existing properties, but if there aren't any properties, it will fallback to an empty array.

Comment: ok thx, for me as a beginner it is quite hard to come to such a clean and compact solution..

Comment: @user2774480 no worries. If you need anymore help, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge values with previous value, whereas in your code you're assigning new values in each iteration

```js
let doc = [{"car": "Ford","prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],"model": "SUV"},{"car": "Ford","prices": ["99","88","77"],"model": "T3"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["33","44","55"],"model": "Subaru"},{"car": "Toyota","prices": ["66", "50", "22"],"model": "Cheyenne"},{"car": "Peugeot","prices": ["1","2","3"],"model" : "503"}];

let final = doc.reduce((op,{car,prices,model:m})=>{
  op[car] = op[car] || {prices:[],model:[]}
  op[car].prices = [...op[car].prices, ...prices]
  op[car].model = [...op[car].model, m]
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug. My library [`blinq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) provides a number of functions that make this kind of transformation easy:

```
const result = blinq(doc)
  .groupBy(c => c.car)
  .select(g => ({
    car: g.key,
    prices: g
      .selectMany(c => c.prices)
      .distinct()
      .toArray(),
    models: g.select(c => c.model).toArray()
  }))
  .toArray();
```

```js
const doc = [{
    "car": "Ford",
    "prices": ["12", "3", "5", "1"],
    "model": "SUV"
  },
  {
    "car": "Ford",
    "prices": ["99", "88", "77"],
    "model": "T3"
  },
  {
    "car": "Toyota",
    "prices": ["33", "44", "55"],
    "model": "Subaru"
  },
  {
    "car": "Toyota",
    "prices": ["66", "50", "22"],
    "model": "Cheyenne"
  },
  {
    "car": "Peugeot",
    "prices": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "model": "503"
  }
];

const {
  blinq
} = window.blinq

const result = blinq(doc)
  .groupBy(c => c.car)
  .select(g => ({
    car: g.key,
    prices: g
      .selectMany(c => c.prices)
      .distinct()
      .toArray(),
    models: g.select(c => c.model).toArray()
  }))
  .toArray();
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq"></script>
```

Comment: Not going to lie, this makes things look a _lot_ more harder to read. Nice library, though.